# Can I ask for help with a specific PACER query?

Tags: discussion, scope

Actually I guess it’s not just PACER, it’s an entire research process.

I am trying to find cases with a specific attorney. I’ve done as much legwork as possible, starting with looking up their bar and court info, through signing up for pacer and cross referencing their site with pacer results, and I’m not seeing the results I expect.

My intent isn’t to get somebody to do the research, it’s to figure out what I’m missing because this is all unfamiliar territory and I don’t understand why I can’t find what I’m looking for, if it’s related to specific court filing practices, missed steps on my part, etc.

Can I ask about it here? It would involve giving the name and site of a specific attorney, and although this attorney has occasionally appeared in mainstream media, it feels like unintentional spam. My question can’t be formed without specific info, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that legal research methodology is quite on topic here. I don't think that it is exactly "off topic" to give an actual name and web page (though it would strongly resemble spam); but it might be "inappropriate". So, if your real question were "how do I find previous cases where Michael Cohen was the attorney of record", you could substitute a pseudonym. This would especially work if you explained what you had already tried that didn't work.

Comment: Well, I’ll give it a shot. It might be tricky, since I actually do know how to find cases with a specific attorney, I’m just having weird trouble finding this specific one. Thanks, what you say makes sense. I suck changing thoughts to words sometimes, “inappropriate” is what I really was trying to ask about.